# How to run a project that written in NetBeans on another computer?

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote a project in NetBeans IDE in my computer, and I ran it. That was OK. I transferred it into my Friend's computer. I ran it with NetBeans, but I got these errors:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: friendspro/Server/RunServer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: friendspro.Server.RunServer.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

///
When I ran my project in my computer in CMD, I got the same error:

```
C:\Users\Blue\Desktop\FriendsPro\src\friendspro\Server>java RunServer  -ORBIniti
alRef NamingServic=corbaloc::localhost:1049/NameService
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RunServer (wrong name
: friendspro/Server/RunServer)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
```

Comment: Both computers need to have the same version of Java.

Comment: @ Hunter McMillen i have jdk1.7 and my firends have 1.6,but i could run another project in my friend's computer . ?!

Comment: Compile your program with Java settings at 1.6. NetBeans will allow you to do this -- check the help files.

Comment: @assylias i read this page but i did not understand what should i do:(

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same error. Your friend has an older Java version. Here's how to target older Java versions in NetBeans: *[Target JDK for Java Applications](https://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/target_jdk)*.

You are running your program incorrectly. You need to do

```
java friendspro.Server.RunServer -ORBIniti ...
```

in your main directory (probably `bin` or `src`).

Comment: Are you sure they are the same?

Comment: no,sorry i made a mistake i got this errors : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6ls465K8JFrZzd3NzctaHNjejQ

Comment: You need to add all external libraries to your classpath. If `chat.ServerOperations` is part of your program make sure you compiled it correctly.

Comment: i recompiled all off them but i got the same errors again :https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6ls465K8JFrbTFqXzVUcHljUGs

Comment: Add `-cp friendspro` to your java arguments.

Answer (score 0):

On your computer, open CMD, `cd` to your source directory and then, as Banthar specified,

```
java friendpro.Server.RunServer ...
```

Comment: i tried it and i got this errors : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6ls465K8JFrZzd3NzctaHNjejQ/edit?pli=1

Comment: looking at the error image it seems like chat.ServerOperations class is missing ...  can u list me your project directory structure.